# Shomer Nagia - How old should a girl be before she becomes shomer

Tags: halacha, negia

At what ages do girls need to apply the rules of "[shomer negia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negiah)" (restricting contact between members of opposite gender)?

Is there a difference between Ashkenazim and Sepharadim?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. I allowed myself to edit your question to make it more compliant with the site rules. Hope this will help you get answers and hope to see you around!